Trigger VS Code hover information box by hovering + holding control
In VS Code, is there a way to show the information box popup on elements like function or class instance words only when pressing the CTRL key and hovering?
By default, it just pops up when I hover in general. This has become rather annoying, especially for working with CSS where seemingly every word I type has an information box. However, I still want to be able to be able to see these boxes.
Ideally, I would like to just be able to hover over the word and hold CTRL to view the info box. When I stop holding CTRL, it would dismiss the box.
I have disabled editor.hover.enabled setting and I have tried setting the editor.action.showHover command shortcut to "Ctrl" but it does not activate.
I have tried setting editor.action.showHover to other key combinations and it seems to work with those. Except that the information box now sticks around until I scroll; not ideal.
I'm also aware of Trigger advanced hover information with keyboard
None of these answers are exactly the same action I'm looking for either though. The editor.action.showDefinitionPreviewHover does a similar thing to editor.action.showHover.
